# How can I inform views in separate windows when using MVC in a Qt/c++ project?

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, qsqltablemodel

I use MVC pattern, sqlite database in my code. I want 
to show my same 
data in different views, in the separate windows at the same time. Also, I want to 
update my data.

I implement the model in a class and I call the model function as needed.

```
QSqlRelationalTableModel* MW_main::relModel()  
{  
    QSqlRelationalTableModel *FTRmodel=new QSqlRelationalTableModel;  
    FTRmodel->setTable("filename");  
    FTRmodel->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnFieldChange);  
    FTRmodel->select();   
    return FTRmodel ;  
}  
void Tables::model()  
{  
    MW_main *mwmain = new MW_main;  
    QSqlRelationalTableModel *FTRmodel=new QSqlRelationalTableModel;  
    FTRmodel = mwmain->relModel ();  
}
```

My code is working. But when i change a data in a window, the others are not aware of updating.

How can i inform other views?

Comment: Use 1 single model for all of your views. Don't create a new instance for each view.

Comment: When you say 'separate windows', do you mean separate processes or single process with several widgets with Qt::Window flag?

Comment: yes, i wanted to say a single model on several widgets. I mean, to declare and implement a model in a class as public, then use it more than one view on separate widgets in other classes and also can update all views in other classes when an update occurs in a view..